# Как избавиться от передачи массива x в метод Add?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = new double[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        x = Class1.Add(x, 5);
    }
}
public class Class1
{
    public static double[] Add(double[] a, double number)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            a[i] = a[i] + number;
        return a;
    }
}
```

И второй вопрос: можно ли что-то сделать, чтобы метод Main выглядел так:

```
static void Main()
{
    var x = new double[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    x.Add(5);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: 1) а зачем? 2) нет

Comment: @aepot 2) почему?

Comment: использовать вместо массива список и всё %)

Comment: а вот зачем в Main `return x;` - не ясно

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/  - почитайте список допустимых подписей Main

Comment: У вас мне кажется есть некая путаница с именованиями. Вот ваш метод `Add()`, он что делает? Добавляет элементы, или их генерирует? Судя по `a[i] + number`, он их генерирует, почему тогда это зовется `Add`? По поводу вопросов: 1. Перенести массив внутрь `Class1`, ибо он к нему относится, а внутри класса сделать методы по добавлению/удалению/изменению/получению значений. 2. По сути можно, методом расширения. Вся проблема заключается в том, что у вас массив, то есть готовый класс, который имеет свои методы, а `Add()` в нем нету. Добавлением методов к существующим классам занимаются расширения.

Comment: В методе Add к значению a[i] прибавляется number и тем самым изменяется a[i]

Comment: Вы можете отредактировать вопрос и добавить в него условие задачи, которую вы решаете? Так будет понятно, как именно вам можно помочь. Сейчас ваши 2 вопроса похожи на "можно ли спать с открытыми глазами" и "можно ли укусить себя за локоть", поэтому я и написал 1) зачем? 2) нет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это вообще к чему здесь? Человек очевидно не понимает `void` ничего не возвращает. Представьте ситуацию, человек спрашивает "как можно наложить себе гипс?" а вы ему "берёте болгарку и пилите". А если он ногу по вашему совету себе отпилит? Вы же не уточнили, что пилить. Ну даже если (в чем я сомневаюсь) поменяет `void` на `int` ну выбросит он туда значение, вы уверены, что ему надо ненулевой exit code возвращать? И ли вам реально все равно, что писать в комментариях?

Comment: @aepot не будь таким агрессивным, отдохни немного))